# What does it mean for a snapshot to be atomic?

Tags: git, version-control

In the following command and explanation, what does the qualifier "***atomic***" mean in "***atomic* snapshots**"? My best guess from the context is something akin to granularity?

```
git reset <commit>

# Move the current branch tip backward to <commit>, reset the staging 
# area to match, but leave the working directory alone. All changes made 
# since <commit> will reside in the working directory, which lets you 
# re-commit the project history using cleaner, more atomic snapshots.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# since <commit> will reside in the working directory, which lets you 
# re-commit the project history using cleaner, more atomic snapshots.
```

In that context I think what's meant is that you can reset HEAD to some previous commit, and then squash all your subsequent changes into a single commit. A commit is the smallest unit of change in a `git` repository, and its often desirable to have a single commit that contains all the changes necessary to add some piece of work to the repo.